# Better way to load information from server database

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, fetch, dispatch-async

I'm loading information from site in json to local Core Data. I've created 2 subclasses of NSManagedObject:

```
@objc(Category)
class Category: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var name: String
}

@objc(Event)
class Event: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var category: String
    @NSManaged var date: String
    @NSManaged var event: String
    @NSManaged var location: String
    @NSManaged var time: String
}
```

And here is the code where I load information in background:

```
func loadAllData(){
    println("loading all data")

    progressCounter = 0

    let source = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_DATA_ADD, 0, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue());

    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(source) {
        [unowned self] in
        self.progressCounter += dispatch_source_get_data(source)
        self.progressView.setProgress(Float(self.progressCounter) / Float(self.maxValue), animated: true)
    }

    dispatch_resume(source)

    let params = ServerConstants.infoParam + "=true"

    // creating request, set its method to POST and append params to request
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: ServerConstants.getInfoURL)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    //request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    //start loading data in background
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){ (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let json = JSON(data: data)

                //println(json)
                self.maxValue = Float(json["categories"].count + json["events"].count)
                println("maxself. - \(self.maxValue)")

                var array = json["categories"]
                var maxIndex = array.count

                var error: NSError?
                for var i: Int = 0; i < maxIndex; i++ {
                    if let moc = self.context {
                        let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: self.context!) as! Category

                        newItem.id = array[i]["id"].string!.toInt()!
                        newItem.name = array[i]["name"].string!

                        dispatch_source_merge_data(source, 1);
                        moc.save(&error)
                    }
                }

                array = json["events"]
                maxIndex = array.count

                for var i: Int = 0; i < maxIndex; i++ {
                    if let moc = self.context {
                        let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Event", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Event

                        newItem.category = array[i]["category"].string!
                        newItem.event = array[i]["event"].string!
                        newItem.location = array[i]["location"].string!
                        newItem.date = array[i]["date"].string!
                        newItem.time = array[i]["time"].string!

                        dispatch_source_merge_data(source, 1);
                        moc.save(&error)
                    }
                }                
                println("done")
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    self.showScreenElements()
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

My server database has about 3600 rows and the downloading process takes ~30-40 seconds to load.

Is there a better way to fetch server's json faster?

When I tried to save only one time at 200 iterations it throw's an error

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

```
for var i: Int = 0; i < maxIndex; i++ {
    if let moc = self.context {
        let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Event", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Event
        newItem.category = array[i]["category"].string!
        ...
        dispatch_source_merge_data(source, 1);
        if i % 200 == 0 {
            moc.save(&error)
        }
    }
}
self.context!.save(&error)
println("done")
```

I'll try to use performBlock and tell you my results.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving too often. Try saving in batches, say after 500 or so inserts.

Also, try switching of the undo manager of the context for this operation. Assuming you have a child context that you can discard:

```
context.undoManager = nil
```

Also, your GCD code is quite complicated. Have you looked at the `performBlock` and `performBlockAndWait` APIs of `NSManagedObjectContext`?